# Do While Loop not working

Tags: c#, do-while

I created below do while loop:

```
ConnectionServerRest connectionServer = ConnectCiscoUnityServer(IP, login, password);
WebCallResult res;
List<UserBase> oUsers;
int page = 10;
int recordsPerPage = 20;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Page:" + page);
    // get first <recordsPerPAge> Users from <page> Page
    res = UserBase.GetUsers(connectionServer, out oUsers, page, recordsPerPage);
    Console.WriteLine("Users returned: " + oUsers.Count);
    page++;
} while (oUsers.Count == 0);
```

I am using pagging to retrieve 20 users per page. I would like to exit the loop when oUsers.Count == 0. When I put int page = 10 the loop is infinity because no result is on 10th page. In case I put int page = 1 it returns 20 records, but exits the loop instead to go to second page. Could anyone of you help me resolve this problem?

Comment: `while (oUsers.Count > 0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Do ... while` executes at least one time and as long the condition is true.

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Page:" + page);
    // get first <recordsPerPAge> Users from <page> Page
    res = UserBase.GetUsers(connectionServer, out oUsers, page, recordsPerPage);
    Console.WriteLine("Users returned: " + oUsers.Count);
    page++;
} while (oUsers.Count != 0); //not equal
```

In your example, it runs once and sees that the condition to "still run" is false, as `oUsers.Count == 0` return false.

Comment: @ironcurtain, I can't say I don't know the feeling :)